# Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have been using custom functions to break out simple mathematics into readable JavaScript, but am getting the following error:

> Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. Try `Utilities.sleep(1000)` between calls. (line 0).

I have tried sleeping for a random time, but that doesn't help. My functions look like this:

```
function conversationGrowthRate(clientCount, initialGrowthRate, conversationCount) {  
  //Utilities.sleep(Math.random() * 30000);
  for (var i = clientCount; i > 10; i--) {
    if (initialGrowthRate > 0) {
      conversationCount += initialGrowthRate
      initialGrowthRate -= 0.000003
    }
  }
  return conversationCount;
}

function conversionGrowth(clientCount, conversationCount, initialConversionRate, conversionGrowthRate, maxConversionRate, coversPerBooking, initialConversationGrowthRate, initialConversationCount) {
  //Utilities.sleep(Math.random() * 30000);
  if (clientCount <= 50) {
    return coversPerBooking * conversationCount * initialConversionRate;
  }
  else {
    var firstFiftyClientConversations = conversationGrowthRate(50,initialConversationGrowthRate, initialConversationCount)*30*50; //~30
    var additionalConversionGrowthRate = (clientCount-50) * conversionGrowthRate;
    var totalConversionRate = initialConversionRate + additionalConversionGrowthRate;
    var additionalClientConversations = conversationGrowthRate(clientCount-50, initialConversationGrowthRate, initialConversationCount) * 30 * (clientCount-50);
    if (totalConversionRate < maxConversionRate) {
      return coversPerBooking * ((firstFiftyClientConversations * initialConversionRate) + (additionalClientConversations * totalConversionRate));
    }
    else {
      return coversPerBooking * (conversationCount * maxConversionRate); 
    }
  }
}

function salesProductivity(currentExecs, prevMonthExecs, prevTwoMonthExecs, prevThreeMonthExecs, prevFourMonthExecs, salesPerExecPerMonth) {
  //Utilities.sleep(Math.random() * 30000);
  var firstMonthHires = currentExecs - prevMonthExecs;
  var secondMonthHires = prevMonthExecs - prevTwoMonthExecs;
  var thirdMonthHires = prevTwoMonthExecs - prevThreeMonthExecs;
  var fourthMonthHires = prevThreeMonthExecs - prevFourMonthExecs;
  var longerHires = prevFourMonthExecs;

  return (secondMonthHires * (0.33 * salesPerExecPerMonth)) + (thirdMonthHires * (0.66 * salesPerExecPerMonth)) + (fourthMonthHires * (1 * salesPerExecPerMonth)) + (longerHires * salesPerExecPerMonth);
}
```

I changed nothing before it started working.

[image]

Comment: Can you please include the script that gets/sets the value into the cells?

Comment: Consider rewriting to use array inputs instead of single cells, as per best practices for custom functions. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization

Comment: @ThumChoonTat Like this, for example: ```=conversationGrowthRate(B4,Summary!$G$29)*30*B4```

Comment: @tehhowch I don't see how I can do this in my use case. Each function depends on a variety of inputs from across the sheet - this example isn't much help, and I still get errors when I try.

Comment: Then you need to restructure your sheet to support array based calculations. You don't show the formulas you use, so we can't tell you any more than that. To me it makes sense that your formulas in a given column should be really similar already - if not, then you have a spreadsheet prone to data entry errors.

Comment: I have posted my formulas above. @tehhowch For example, ```=conversationGrowthRate(B4,Summary!$G$29)*30*B4``` or ones with many inputs like ```=Summary!$G$4*(conversionGrowth(I4,I6,Summary!$G$27,Summary!$G$28,Summary!$G$30,Summary!$G$26,Summary!$G$29,Summary!$G$7))```

Comment: I believe what the error meant was you are applying `conversationGrowthRate`, `conversionGrowth` and `salesProductivity` in multiple cells and the number of function calls is at least as much as the number of cells applied.

You can either convert your functions into [Google sheets functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273) (which is difficult to maintain) or follow @tehhowch's approach and use [`onChange` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange())

Comment: @thum I didn't recommend an "on change" trigger. I recommended being able to use one call from the sheet to the script with arrays of the respective inputs, and let the function return an array of the respective outputs.

Comment: The answer over here helped for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14609691/197993

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets runs custom functions remotely through a service called `exec`. If there are "too many" calls (according to some undocumented quota, or, at least, I haven't found any such documentation) to any custom functions, this error will be emitted.

If the calls are happening because many cells are calling the custom functions, I don't see how `Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)` can help since `exec` would be called before `sleep` is (indeed, it'll be `exec` that'll be calling `sleep` whether directly or indirectly).

As some comments have mentioned, converting the function to accept ranges and return arrays (and changing the sheet to accommodate said function) is the way to go (until Google add smarter throttling).

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any google service that's hitting a usage quota.

```
while(true) {
  try {
    return '<whatever's hitting the quota>';
  }
  catch(error) {
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

- It doesn't give up
- It doesn't impose a delay unless needed