# calculate range of values entered by user Custom function Google Appscript

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling

I want to use arrayformula for my custom function if possible because I want to input a range of values

I also get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from null.`

Also, this: `Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls`

```
 var regExp = new RegExp("Item: ([^:]+)(?=\n)");
 var matches=new regExp(input);
 return matches[0];

}
```

Really appreciated some help

**Edit**:
Based on the second picture, I also try  using this regex formula to find word start with "Billing address"

But for the first picture, I used regex formula to find word start with "Item"

The error appears the same for both custom function.

[image: TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from null.]

[image: Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls]

Comment: Hello @Muqri! Would you mind **sharing the code you are using** since the snippet you shared doesn't provide too much insight into the issue you are having. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `custom function` which finds all the strings that start with `Item` or `item` and extracts the contents from after the finding, you can use the code provided below. The regular expression is checked by using the `match()` function and returns the desired result; otherwise, it will return `null`.

```js
function ITEM(input) {
  var regEx = /(?:I|i)tem\s*(.*)$/;
  var matches = input.match(regEx);
  if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
    return matches[1];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

If you want to use the `RegExp` like you did in the code you have shared, you should use `\\` instead of `\`.

For checking and verifying the `regular expressions` you can use [this site](https://regex101.com/).

The `Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.` error message you are getting is due to the fact that you are trying to call the custom function on too many cells - for example dragging the custom function on too many cells at once. You can check more about this error message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494465/service-invoked-too-many-times-in-a-short-time-exec-qps-google-sheets).

Comment: Thank you in advanced...I will try to try :)